# Element fade on scroll with keyframe doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I found this code: [DEMO](http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/xEjCA)

When you scroll over the element, the element appears. But, the effect is only an opacity change.

I tried to add a keyframe animation when the element appears but, when the first element appears, all others elements appear at the same time.

[DEMO with Keyframe](http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/KcBeL)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

              $(this).css({'opacity':'1'});
              $('.e1').addClass('animated fadeInUp')
              $('.e2').addClass('animated fadeInLeft')  

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tell the each function which elements to add the animations to and remove the bit changing the opacity, the opacity change is already apart of the animation.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Hvd9g/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each(function (i) {

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
// Changes made here 
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('e1')) {
                    $(this).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                }
                if ($(this).hasClass('e2')) {
                    $(this).addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
                }
            }

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Very useful technique

Comment: @user3245085 Glad to help. Don't forget to add your code to the question next time. Adding demos from codepen or jsFiddle is a good idea, but your question should still be answerable without them.